# How to download CTU-IoT-Malware-Capture in IoT-23?

Tags: download, iot, malware, ips

Stratosphere IPS Team (IoT-23) doesn't permit me to download all CTU-IoT-Malware-Capture.
I want CTU-IoT-Malware-Capture-7-1 to complete my research.
Thanks :((
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icaIV.png)

Answer (score 0):

this is CTU-IoT-Malware-Capture-7-1

## IoT Lab Capture

- Description:
- Probable Malware Name:
- MD5: c76a2520b7454788d127b7e41ae3d9be
  SHA1: 66883e8b7d2e34d9da2bdd48a6e28b5a01ccf93d
- SHA256: fdb74bae02106a08e1afa9ac408b8d97521f9414bbb6af874f6574a75656dfc8
- Password of zip file: infected